# IFrame scroll bars not coming on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, scrollbar

I am using an IFrame to make show some content from some other domain. The problem is that I can use a specified height and width (which I am using) and the content inside the IFrame cannot be accommodated completely in the IFrame. Hence, I need scrollbars.

I used the following html code -

```
**<iframe style = "overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;" src =       "http://shopsocial.ly/merchant/fanpage?merchant_name=cafepress"
     height = "400" width = "500">**
```

This works fine in Firefox. But in Chrome I'm not getting any scrollbar in the IFrame. I have searched this problem and have tried many things all of which did not solve my problem. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Works fine in chrome 13.0.772.0 dev-m!

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome 11.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the CSS style you could use the [scrolling](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp) property of the iframe and set it to `yes` (i.e. always display scrollbars):

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://domain.com" height="400" width="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: I have also tried scrolling = "yes". Again, it works on Firefox but not on Chrome. The domain I've used in the example is open and can be used by you to check. Does the IFrame scrollbar in anyway depend on it's content because other pages in the IFrame is rendered with scrollbars but not the one I've used in the example above.

Comment: I found out the problem which I think is a bug on Chrome-

The content which is being displayed in the IFrame has its body defined with the tag <body style = "overflow:hidden;">. If you remove the style element in the body then the IFrame renders with the scrollbars as desired.

On firefox, it causes no such problem.

Do you think it is a Chrome-bug or HTML needs to be written that way?

Comment: I see. Yes, that would be the reason you don't see the scrollbars. Is there any way you can make the iframe big enough to make the content fit (i.e. no scrollbars required)?

Comment: Sadly not. Even if I do it, the size of the content in the IFrame will vary and hence that solution, in my opinion, will not serve to be fit. Unfortunately, I need the overflow:hidden as well. Anything which can be done?

Comment: Do you control the iframe's page html? If so, you could add some JavaScript that checks if you're using Chrome and are displaying the page in an iframe, and it that case remove the 'overflow:hidden' style. I can't think of another solution round this problem. Does it happen only in Chrome, or also in other Webkit browsers like Safari?

Comment: I haven't tried Safari. As someone reported that the error is not coming in Chrome 13.0 dev, so I think that in future versions of Chrome, it will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I do have control on the iframe's html. So I think that I will do what you have suggessted and let you know but I am not convinced completely about the solution - it's not neat

Comment: I agree it's not very neat. But as you say, it seems fixed in later version of Chrome, so it would only affect older versions.

Comment: Chrome has also a nasty bug with that in dev-tools. When `scrolling="no"` was set, and over the dev-tool you turn it to "yes" or you remove the property, you will see no changes. But if you remove it from the sourcefile and reload the page, then you will see the scrollbar. Chrome v61.0.3163.100

Answer (score 6):

In your iframe content add inline:

```
<body style="overflow:auto;">
```

or in the css file attached to the iframe

```
html, body {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

and of course as recommended by Tom make sure you use `scrolling="yes"` and `style="overflow:visible;"` on the iframe:

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://example.com" style="overflow:visible;"></iframe>
```

If it still does not work then try to wrap the iframe like this:

```
<div style="overflow:visible; height:400px;">

    <iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://example.com" style="overflow:visible; height:2000px;"></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: I'll upvote for the overflow:auto part, but in many cases you have no control over the styles of the iframe content. In my case I did, and used overflow:auto and also overflow-x:hidden. Doing just overflow-y: auto on the iframe's html/body did not work. For Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Yap Tom is absolutely right you can use

```
<iframe style="overflow:visible; width:400px; height:400px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="yourfile.html"></iframe>
```

and it should be work as i have tested.

If it still does not work then update Chrome to latest version. :)

Comment: Does not work with svg content... using latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

To make this scrollable on all mobile devices (specially iPhone devices), you will need to add CSS to the div around the iframe:

```
<div style="overflow: auto!important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;">
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://example.com" height="400" width="500">Loading...</iframe>
</div>
```