# iframe scrollbar disappears in Chrome on a Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, iframe

I have a full page iframe, but in chrome the scroll bar initially loads then disappears, the room is there for it, and you can use it but it's not visible. Works perfect in safari and firefox and chrome on pc, however on a mac you see the well of the scroll bar, but the bar itself is missing.

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#me-branding-bar{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ff9900;
}
#me-content{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ff9900;
}
#me-content iframe{
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

```
<div id="me-branding-bar">

</div>

<div id="me-content">
    <iframe border="0" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="<?php echo $url;?>" style="overflow:visible;height:100%;width:100%;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RYwty/

Comment: Can try some of the suggestions [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199892/iframe-scroll-bars-not-coming-on-chrome

Comment: I get a scrollbar in chrome (v30.0.1599.101) for your jsfiddle example.

Comment: @kosherjellyfish I did try that suggestion before posting

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER are you on a mac or pc? I have latest Chrome on a mac and don't see it...

Comment: @keeg I'm on a windows pc (v7). Could it be a mac thing?

Comment: Yep, mac thing... I'll adjust the question

Comment: Chrome on Mac may not show a bar well. Scroll bar appears only while scrolling for me.

Comment: OS X 10.8.5 Chrome: Version 31.0.1650.63

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Why does the scrollbar disappear in an `<iframe>` when using Chrome on a Mac?

That's a pretty broad question when your `<iframe>` contains an entire page from an external site. Let's break it down into a few steps.

> <sup>The following examples assumes that you use Chrome on a Mac.</sup>

#### Make a simple test

Create a very simple HTML page, put it in an `<iframe>`, and view it in Chrome on a Mac ([DEMO](//jsfiddle.net/VWLD5/)).

[image]

The scrollbar does not disappear. Everything seems fine. So it's most likely something on the external site is causing the problem.

#### Debug the external site

The symptom is that the scrollbar actually appears for a very short time before it disappears, but the page is still scrollable. Maybe JavaScript is causing the problem? Let's disable JavaScript and [try it out](//fiddle.jshell.net/RYwty/show/light/).

It turns out the scrollbar does not disappear when JavaScript is disabled. So something loaded by JavaScript is causing the problem. Further debugging reveals that a flash object is the culprit.

[image]

#### Make another test

Create two simple HTML test pages and add a flash object to one of them. Put them into different `<iframe>`s and [compare them](//jsfiddle.net/EN9dv/1/) to see the difference.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
```

It turns out the one with a flash object does not have a visible scrollbar.

[image]

#### Conclusion

The scrollbar does not disappear in a normal `<iframe>`, but the ones with a flash object. It may be a bug, or it may be an intentional dirty hack. Many flash ads and videos are served in `<iframe>`s and having a scrollbar in them isn't pretty.

But the point is, you are serving external contents in your `<iframe>` and these are things that you have no control of.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $url;?>"></iframe>
```

Maybe you can try your best to solve an issue or two, but there are dozens of things happening in an external page that can break things here and there. People can even [prevent their sites from being placed in an `<iframe>`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/) with a little help from JavaScript and HTTP headers. As long as the page loads, you should be happy about it. Don't bother too much about minor details like the disappearing scrollbar. Only worry about it when the page isn't actually scrollable. You are talking a scrolling on a Mac. Most of the time this is done by gestures, not scrollbars.

If you do want more control of the external contents, consider loading it on server side with [cURL](//php.net/curl) and [modifying the contents with HTML parsers](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: That is very strange, I wouldn't expect for the iframe contents to have that sort of effect on the scrollbar itself shouldn't cross domain controls prevent that?

Comment: The effect is only on the scrollbar of the document inside the iframe itself, not that of the main page, so there is nothing involving cross domain here. This behavior particularly impacts you because you use a full-page iframe. And this could even be a bug, so I guess no one would *expect* that.

Comment: right... it does work in all other browsers... even chrome on pc

Comment: That's why it may be a bug, and one that you should not worry too much about because it is on a Mac, and very few people scroll with scrollbars on a Mac. You don't have control over everything. Your best bet is to submit a bug report and see what they find out.

Answer (score 2):

The code below seems to solve the iframe scrollbar problem in Chrome on a Mac.

This fix is cross-browser compatible with Firefox, Safari, and Opera on Mac and PC.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxjrd/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="me-branding-bar"></div>

    <div id="me-content">
        <iframe src="http://tsn.ca" height="100%" width="100%" class="iframeclass"></iframe>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
        #me-branding-bar{overflow:hidden;z-index:102;width:100%;height:40px;position:relative;background-color:#ff9900;}
        #me-content{height:100%;width:100%;position:relative;border:1px solid #ff9900;}
        #me-content iframe{border:1px solid #000;}

.iframeclass::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:10px;
}

.iframeclass::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}

.iframeclass::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.iframeclass::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.iframeclass::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
   margin:0; 
   padding:0;
}
html, body{
   height:100%; 
   width:100%;
}
#me-branding-bar{
   width:100%; 
   height:10%; 
   position:relative; 
   background-color:#ff9900; 
   display:block;
}
#me-content{
   display:block; 
   height:90%; 
   width:100%; 
   position:relative; 
   border:none;
}
#me-content iframe{
   border:none; 
   display:block; 
   overflow:auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{-webkit-appearance: scrollbarthumb-vertical;}
```

ant try that [link 1](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/displaying-scroll-bar) [link 2](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/nP2Kn5Xjw60)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYwty/8/)

Comment: try now but first check links maybe you have something wrong with a settings

Comment: Depends on the site you iframe. Same code works for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the styles from your html and add scrolling="yes" >> http://jsfiddle.net/95Tes/

```
<!--same code as before just remove your css styles from the html -->
```

Comment: Ah. Ok so I just tried using another source site and it works fine. something on the http://www.tsn.ca site is overriding the scrolls. H/O

Comment: I think it's a chrome mac bug, it works fine in all other browser

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.I do not have mac so please do not give any negative points,I hope.I want to say you do not use different style in css rule as well as html style.Here you used like that

```
<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.tsn.ca" style="overflow:visible;height:100%;width:100%;"></iframe>


#me-content iframe{
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

See the image in the other tab or save the image at first and see it to more clear!
[image]

Please use this code which I  have modified css as well as html

```
       <style>
*{
    margin:0px;
    paddinig:0px;
    }

body,html{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#me-branding-bar{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ff9900;
}
#clearboth {
   clear:both;
}
#me-content{
    height:calc(100% - 40px);
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ff9900;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
}
#me-content iframe{
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

       </style>
```

Here is the modified html

```
         <div id="me-branding-bar">

        </div>

        <div id="clearboth"></div>

        <div id="me-content">
            <iframe border="0" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
            src="http://www.tsn.ca"></iframe>
        </div>
```

Hope it will work!

Comment: I think, Asraful's code may help because same attribute may not applied in single value..try above code...

Comment: Bar still disappears in chrome on a mac... :(