# How to add scrolling tollbar to the iframe with pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, iframe

I have a modal with pdf:

```
  <div ng-if="$root.isie11">
       <iframe src="file.pdf" class="pdf">
       </iframe>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!$root.isie11">
       <object data="file.pdf"
            type='application/pdf' class="pdf" >
       </object>
  </div>
```

As you can see if browser is IE I use iframes in other cases object. In object the pdf comes with scrollbar. Althought its only 1 page its need to be scrollable because of a modal size. In Iframe there is no scrollBar.

I tried adding : `scrolling: yes` with now effects

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199892/iframe-scroll-bars-not-coming-on-chrome

Comment: @Pugazh I already tried it.